# C2338 incorrect parameter type for the callable object in 'then'

Tags: visual-c++, concurrency, task

I am learning how to properly catch exceptions that occur in parallel tasks. I have included test code below inspired by msdn's when_all Windows Store example code at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dd492427.aspx#when_all. My C++ code works unless I uncomment the throw and .then statements. I thought my callable functor object was 'concurrency::task< Xxx >', but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ppltasks.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int wmain()
{
  // Start multiple tasks and put them into a vector. Throw and catch an exception on one of the tasks. 
  std::vector< concurrency::task< int > > tasks;
  tasks.push_back( concurrency::create_task( [] () -> int { return 3; } ) );
  tasks.push_back( concurrency::create_task( [] () -> int
  {
//    throw 20;
    return 4;
  } ) );
  tasks.push_back( concurrency::create_task( [] () -> int { return 5; } ) );

  // When all tasks have finished...
  auto jointask = when_all( begin( tasks ), end( tasks ) )
  //  .then( [ tasks ] ( concurrency::task< int > prevTask )->concurrency::task< int >
  //{
  //  try
  //  {
  //  }
  //  catch( ... )
  //  {
  //    // handle all exceptions
  //    std::wcout << "All tasks have finished and exceptions handled" << std::endl;
  //  }
  //} )
    ;
  jointask.wait();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out the vector-of-tasks case with exceptions. Having two when-all s doesn't look right though, but at least it runs for all 4 cases (throw, no-throw, value-based continuation, task-based continuation). My break-through in understanding was realizing that the when_all .then continuation return values should respectively be a vector for value-based and a task> for task-based. I had it the other way (task for value-based and nothing for task-based) which doesn't make sense. The error code which is the title of this posting now makes sense. Here is the code:

```
#include <ppltasks.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace concurrency;
using namespace std;

int wmain()
{
  wcout << L"Running a vector of tasks..." << endl;

  // Create a task that throws.
  vector< concurrency::task< int > > tasks;
  tasks.push_back( create_task( [] () -> int { return 3; } ) );
  tasks.push_back( create_task( [] () -> int
  {
    throw 20; // comment out for no throw case
    return 4;
  } ) );
  tasks.push_back( create_task( [] () -> int { return 5; } ) );

  // Attach two continuations to the task. The first continuation is value-based; the second is task-based. Both cases are necessary to handle the throw and no-throw cases correctly.

  // Task-based continuation.
  try
  {
    // Value-based continuation. 
    auto c1 = when_all( begin( tasks ), end( tasks ) ).then( [] ( vector< int > resultsVect )
    {
      // We don't expect to get here because one of the antecedent vector tasks always throws.
      wcout << L"In value-based continuation task which only runs in no throw case." << endl;
    } );

    auto c2 = when_all( begin( tasks ), end( tasks ) ).then( [] ( task< vector< int > > resultsVectTask )
    {
      // We do expect to get here because task-based continuations are scheduled even when the antecedent task throws. 
      try
      {
        wcout << L"In task-based continuation which is always run with or without a throw." << endl;
      }
      catch( const exception& e )
      {
        wcout << L"Caught exception from previous task: " << e.what() << endl;
      }
    } );

    ( c1 && c2 ).wait();
  }
  catch( ... )
  {
    wcout << L"Caught exception while waiting for all the tasks to finish." << endl;
  }
}
/* Output: (no throw case)
Running a vector of tasks...
In value-based continuation task which only runs in no throw case.
In task-based continuation which is always run with or without a throw.
*/
/* Output: (one of tasks in vector throws and exception)
Running a vector of tasks...
In task-based continuation which is always run with or without a throw.
Caught exception while waiting for all the tasks to finish.
*/
```